# Putting nodes in linked list in order

Tags: c++, linked-list, insertion

So what I have not been able to do for the life of me is put this new node into the linked list in order by their `startbyte` and `endbytes`. Then I need it to look if the nodes are right next to each other, and if they are. Make them into just one big node.

Here is some of the code I have that works to free the memory from the first list, but after I create the new node I cant figure out a way that works, I have tried multiple different things.

```
void release_memory(const int job)
{
    ALLOCPTR t = alloclist;
    FREEPTR f = freelist;
    ALLOCPTR prev = alloclist;

    while(t!=NULL)
    {           
        if(t->id == job )
        {               
            if(t==alloclist)
                {
                    alloclist=alloclist->next;
                }
            else 
                {
                    prev->next = t->next;
                }

            FREEPTR newfreenode = new FREE_NODE;
            newfreenode->start_byte = t->start_byte;
            newfreenode->end_byte = t->end_byte;
            newfreenode->size = t->size;

            while(f->next!=NULL)
            {
                f=f->next;//
            }

            f->next = newfreenode;

            checkIfFreeTogether();                                      
        }

        prev=t;
        t=t->next;          
}
```

An example of what i need done is this

```
before any memory freeing
JOB      MEMORY 
1        1-49
2        50-99
3        100-199 

After freeing 2 and 3
job        memory
1          1-49
FREE      50-99
FREE      100-199
After  creating one big free node out of the two 

job      memory 
1        1-49
FREE    50-199
```

Comment: can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve? I get you are trying to do something with the list's nodes and MSB, LSB or possibly all the bytes of a node's value. But can't figure out what...

Comment: What if `freelist` is `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just putting the new node at the end of the `freelist`, check the previous nodes `end_byte` compared to the new nodes `start_byte`, as well as the new nodes `end_byte` compared to the next nodes `start_byte`. This way the list stays sorted and it's easy to combine nodes of contiguous memory areas.